# vscode-haskell extension cannot change ghc version

Tags: haskell, vscode-extensions

I am having problems when using the vscode-haskell extension.

I am using ghcup to manage all my haskell related stuff.

[image: Haskell TUI output]

I want to use haskell 9.4.8 for my exercise, but the hls is keeping popping this and unable to provide autocomplete support. Can anyone help?

[image]

My Vscode Workspace settings are

```json
{
  "haskell.manageHLS": "GHCup",
  "haskell.serverEnvironment": {
    "PATH": "${HOME}/.ghcup/bin:$PATH"
  },
  "haskell.toolchain": {
    "ghc": "9.4.8",
    "hls": "2.5.0.0",
    "cabal": "recommended"
  }
}
```

[image]

```
2024-01-18T03:15:08.330017Z | Error | LSP: no handler for: "textDocument/didOpen"
2024-01-18T03:15:08.330316Z | Debug | LSP: set new config: {
  "checkProject": true,
  "formattingProvider": "brittany",
  "ghcupExecutablePath": "",
  "indentationRules": { "enabled": true },
  "logFile": "",
  "manageHLS": "GHCup",
  "maxCompletions": 40,
  "metadataURL": "",
  "openDocumentationInHackage": true,
  "openSourceInHackage": true,
  "plugin": {
    "alternateNumberFormat": { "globalOn": true },
    "cabal": {
      "codeActionsOn": true,
      "completionOn": true,
      "diagnosticsOn": true
    },
    "callHierarchy": { "globalOn": true },
    "changeTypeSignature": { "globalOn": true },
    "class": { "codeActionsOn": true, "codeLensOn": true },
    "eval": {
      "config": { "diff": true, "exception": false },
      "globalOn": true
    },
    "explicit-fields": { "globalOn": true },
    "explicit-fixity": { "globalOn": true },
    "fourmolu": { "config": { "external": false } },
    "gadt": { "globalOn": true },
    "ghcide-code-actions-bindings": { "globalOn": true },
    "ghcide-code-actions-fill-holes": { "globalOn": true },
    "ghcide-code-actions-imports-exports": { "globalOn": true },
    "ghcide-code-actions-type-signatures": { "globalOn": true },
    "ghcide-completions": {
      "config": { "autoExtendOn": true, "snippetsOn": true },
      "globalOn": true
    },
    "ghcide-hover-and-symbols": { "hoverOn": true, "symbolsOn": true },
    "ghcide-type-lenses": { "config": { "mode": "always" }, "globalOn": true },
    "hlint": {
      "codeActionsOn": true,
      "config": { "flags": [  ] },
      "diagnosticsOn": true
    },
    "importLens": { "codeActionsOn": true, "codeLensOn": true },
    "moduleName": { "globalOn": true },
    "ormolu": { "config": { "external": false } },
    "overloaded-record-dot": { "globalOn": true },
    "pragmas-completion": { "globalOn": true },
    "pragmas-disable": { "globalOn": true },
    "pragmas-suggest": { "globalOn": true },
    "qualifyImportedNames": { "globalOn": true },
    "rename": { "config": { "crossModule": false }, "globalOn": true },
    "retrie": { "globalOn": true },
    "semanticTokens": {
      "config": {
        "classMethodToken": "method",
        "classToken": "class",
        "dataConstructorToken": "enumMember",
        "functionToken": "function",
        "patternSynonymToken": "macro",
        "recordFieldToken": "property",
        "typeConstructorToken": "enum",
        "typeFamilyToken": "interface",
        "typeSynonymToken": "type",
        "typeVariableToken": "typeParameter",
        "variableToken": "variable"
      },
      "globalOn": false
    },
    "splice": { "globalOn": true },
    "stan": { "globalOn": false }
  },
  "promptBeforeDownloads": "true",
  "releasesDownloadStoragePath": "",
  "releasesURL": "",
  "serverEnvironment": { "PATH": "${HOME}/.ghcup/bin:$PATH" },
  "serverExecutablePath": "",
  "serverExtraArgs": "",
  "toolchain": { "cabal": "recommended", "ghc": "9.4.8", "hls": "2.5.0.0" },
  "trace": { "client": "debug", "server": "messages" },
  "upgradeGHCup": true
}
```

Here I attach the output of vscode-haskell.

Comment: Can you go to Output > Haskell -tab in the bottom pane and include the logs?

Comment: I have also added the screenshot here

Comment: Looks like your project is a stack project in which case it's `stack.yaml`s resolver which controls the ghc versoion. Either change the resolver version or switch over to using cabal.

Comment: But my stack.yml only specifies ? 

# Set this to true if you want debug logs.
#
# These can be VERY verbose, so we suggest turning them off
# unless you really need them.
debug: false

# Use this to change the Haskell version used to run your code
# on Codecrafters.
#
# Available versions: haskell-9.4
language_pack: haskell-9.4

No patch version is specified...

Comment: Thx. After I changed the resolver version from lts-21.11 to lts-21.25, it works now... Thx... I was keeping searching for 9.4.6 but to no avail. Problem solved

Comment: Great! I added an answer to this question, could you accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is a stack project which means that `resolver` field in `stack.yaml` controls the ghc version and not GHCUp. For example, resolver version `lts-21.25` has ghc version 9.4.8.

Change the resolver version to `lts-21.25` and that should fix it.